# Hollow semi-circle with thick border

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to achieve the shape in the image below.
Like an arched semi-circle with a thick border and a hole in the middle.

I tried it with the *Solidify Modifier*, but this only seems to work as long as I don't apply a subdivision. Is there a better way than to construct the mesh by hand?

[image]

/e: Thank you for all your answers! Insane to see how many different approaches can lead to a similar result. I didn't even know that geometry nodes could be used to create shapes. I'll keep learning.

Comment: If you apply a Subdivision Surface modifier you just need to create some support edge loops and it will sharpen the edges

Comment: Or in edit mode select edge and Shift+E (Crease) set 1

Comment: .. it's common to follow up  a _Solidify_  modifier with an angle-based _Bevel_, to generate the support-loops @moonboots is talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for fun, in the spirit of our @Gorgious, this can be done purely with old-school modifiers, starting with a single vertex at the object-origin:

[image]

[image]

Comment: sooo shiny! i love it +1 :D

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I gave up trying to play node-golf with you and Chris.. so the G&T at the 19th is on me :)

Comment: what is G&T?????

Comment: @Chris...  Gin and Tonic, Ice. Slice. Oh.... and the dress is 'casual' .. (Plus-fours, tweed jacket, tartan socks. old-school tie.)

Comment: hehe yeah plain old modifiers are not dead :) At least until we get bevel and screw nodes in GN ! Although I admit I don't miss the vertical modifier stack we could get in complex setups at all

Comment: Hello @Gorgious! _Screw_ can be done, with duped extrusion and _Set Position_ (It's ludicrous, of course).. _Bevel_ is holding out :)

Answer (score 9):

what about a geometry nodes solution?

with this node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Comment: Why not making it complicated  ^^

Comment: of course, you have to scare people how damn hard it is to learn Blender and geometry nodes so that they don't use it and we become billionaires alone....!!! :D

Comment: I will recreate this without any hope of understanding what I'm doing. But I'll try.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an easy and simple *Geometry Nodes* setup with a Solidify Modifier. You can easily adjust the Resolution, Arc's radius & sweep angle, object's extrusion and scale, and the thickness.

[image]

Demonstration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great! I wish I could pick more answers as the solution!